# How to get pipeline id of the first pipeline if first pipeline trigger another pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In our ADF application pipeline A is invoking pipeline B. I want to capture the run ID so I used the @pipeline().RunId to capture it. But while executing the two run ID  Which is as per design. But I want to capture the run ID of pipeline A from pipeline B.

Any idea how to capture these details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a system variable like TriggeredByPipelineRunId

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Nandan points , you also have System variable named TriggeredByPipelineName . I do find name more helpful then guid :) .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables

[image]